# :before to all children except :first-child

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation. I'm trying to separate each nav item with a "|" (pipe) using only css.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
</ul
```

Right now it looks like this

```
First   Second   Third   Fourth   Fifth
```

I want it to look like this

```
First | Second | Third | Fourth | Fifth
```

I'm able to use css in order to put a "|" before each `<li>`

```
li:before {
    content:"|";
}
```

How ever the result is

```
|  First | Second | Third | Fourth | Fifth
```

How do I do this with out adding the "|" to the first item?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class:

```css
li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "|";
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "|";
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the nth-child selector to target all elements after the first

```
li:nth-child(n+2):before {
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

other option :)

```css
li {
  display: inline-block
}
li + li:before {
  content: '|';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this rule in addition to your current one.

```
li:before:first-child {
    content: none;
}
```

Pretty sure that will do it.

Comment: Pseudo-elements must be at the end of the selector: `li:first-child:before`.

Comment: Thanks @Katana314 for idea and @Oriol for correction - saved me in a situation where `:not(:first-child)` broke other rules - see used [here](https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:numbered_headings#edit_to_exclude_the_first_h1_page_title_from_numbering) for numbering headings except first